# Excel update notification - Lotus Notes

Tags: excel, lotus-notes

I am very new to all of this, but I have the following problem. I have a Excel worksheet that is shared on my company's server, and I would like to send an automated email to different users notifying that this file has been updated. We work with lotus notes, is that possible ?

I tried the following code but I isn't working

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

    With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
        .Introduction = "Hello, Tvoloria! - the workbook was saved by " & Environ("USERNAME") & " at " & Format(Now(), "ddd dd mmm yy hh:mm")
        .Item.To = "asd@asd.com"
        .Item.Subject = "Workbook Saved!"
        .Item.display
        '.Item.send
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this to send an email

```
Sub test()

  Subject = "Workbook Saved!"
  body = "Hello, Tvoloria! - the workbook was saved by " & Environ("USERNAME") & " at " & Format(Now(), "ddd dd mmm yy hh:mm")
  Recipient = "you@xx.com"
  CopyTo = "you@xx.com"

  Set Session = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
  Set Database = Session.GETDATABASE("", "")
  If Database.IsOpen = False Then Database.OPENMAIL
  Set Document = Database.CreateDocument

  With Document
    .SendTo = Recipient
    .CopyTo = CopyTo
    .Subject = Subject
    .body = body
    .SaveMessageOnSend = True
    .PostedDate = Now()
    .Send 0, Recipient
  End With


  Set Document = Nothing
  Set Database = Nothing
  Set Session = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Imran, thankyou very much for your support. I tried it and seems to work fine but only when I run the Macro, is there a way to make it automated ?

Comment: Just put the whole code in your Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Comment: As you define .SendTo there is no need to define the Recipient with .Send. Everything else is fine.

Answer (score 1):

To send mails using Lotus Notes you need to use the Lotus Notes Classes, not some Microsoft stuff you found "somewhere out there".

In case of an installed Notes Client you can use OLE:

```
Dim ses as Object
Dim db as Object
Dim memo as Object

Set ses = CreateObject( "Notes.NotesSession" ) '- NotesSession is the root for every action over OLE
'- create an empty database object
Set db = ses.GetDatabase( "" , "" )
'- open users mailfile
Call db.OpenMail
'- Create a new Mail
Set memo = db.CreateDocument()
'- Fill all information
With memo
  .Form = "Memo"
  .SendTo = "asd@asd.com"
  .Subject = "Workbook Saved!"
  .Body = "Hello, Tvoloria! - the workbook was saved by " & Environ("USERNAME") & " at " & Format(Now(), "ddd dd mmm yy hh:mm")
  .Send( False )
```

This code is just to demonstrate the idea, it is not tested and might throw some errors. It needs the Lotus Notes Client to be installed and started.

Comment: It's preferable using the COM object (early binding), because using OLE requires that the Notes client is open and logged in to run. Using COM, the script can prompt the user for the password for the NotesID if needed, as it will start the COM server in case the client is not open.